# Why didn't T-1000 mimic T-800?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Well, T-1000 had touched T-800 a lot of times.

Both are cyborgs - not as easy to guess the trick as it was with John's stepmom and Sarah, where T-1000 failed portraying the human behavior and stuff.

Is it the greater volume issue? But what about the floor and the guy in the asylum - greater volume as well?

Is it the complex systems issue? But it needed only T-800 appearence, not the mechanism.

Is it an Austrian accent issue? But sorry my English - not so perfect as well))

UPD: ok, "larger people restriction" and "the original T-800 is always around John" facts make sense.

What about pretending T-800 has lost its arms (like it lost one) or legs (like another T-800 did in the first movie) after disabling the original defender in the last fight? John will run to help, like he did in the final.

It would be only a part of the thing it had touched, but it's something like policeman's clothes-only and all the bugs after the nitrogen. By the way, these bugs could intercept my plan, hmm...

Certainly, I'm not *that* serious about it, just a little "I would"-style fantasy)

Comment: There's no real reason T-1000 couldn't, it just didn't decide to do that.  Its a good idea, but the T-1000 must have felt it wasn't worth it.  Also it wouldn't work if the original T-800 was still present next to the target.  You could use air pockets inside of the T-1000 to simulate a larger size.

Comment: That would have been a really neat scene. Probably better than the T-1000's taking the form of Sarah.

Comment: well, I always wondered why the t-800 didnt pick up the liquid nitrogen frozed t-1000 and just throw him in the steel when he had the chance. I guess the answer is that AI might be realistic but it still has flaws

Comment: Because the T-800 had different cybernetic skin, it was incompatible to the T-1000s sensors. Why would Skynet allow its later model mimic its previous model? It would make no sense. Especially after sending thousand of these things to fight on its front lines, it was trying to do away with using the same face that humans would probably recognize. So what did it do? It created the T-1000, which could imitate anything it touches (only organic human skin, not synthetic.)

Comment: Didn't the T-800 say the T-1,000 couldn't form complex machines?

Comment: Because unlike Linda Hamilton and the Stantons, Arnold doesn't have an identical twin sibling. In 1991, green screen was not yet up to the task.

Comment: @Nu Daq: To attack. It can imitate physical appearance of anything at or greater than its volume. So the only thing it would be imitating would be the body of the T-800 and anything on the outside. If you were to ask it (and let's say it had a good sense of humor enough to offer you a laugh before it probed you to death) to imitate the entire T-800 skeleton to the last part; it would have a hard time doing that.

Answer (score 8):

No reason it couldn't. However, consider what the T-1000 has observed, not what we have observed. He had no way of knowing the paternalistic place that the T-800 had taken in John's life. So the one opportunity that the T-1000 had to do something like this, where nobody was around, it instead took the form of John's mother who John would rush to without thinking. It was the right choice as we saw, but the wrong timing.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it's true. T-1000 surprised me: after it has pierced John's mom, heard her yelling of pain and "f u" still not killing her quickly - but that's another story)

Answer (score 2):

It could have, but why would it?

The T-800 was wanted by the police for the station massacre in 1984.

For the T-1000 to assume that form, it would draw unnecessary attention to itself and eliminate the intelligence it was gaining from listening to the police radio as they searched for that fugitive.

The only time it really has an opportunity to try and trick John Connor in person is when it impersonates his mother.

Comment: How would the T-1000 know what happened in 1984?

Comment: It was public record that someone who met the description of the T-800 attacked the police station in 1984. It's specifically mentioned in Terminator 2.

Comment: It had another opportunity. In the steel mill, the T-1000 had just wedged the T-800's arm in a gear. Then it went to look for John and Sarah, who were still together. They saw him coming, so they turned around and Sarah put John on a conveyor belt (this leads to the encounter between Sarah and the T-1000). If the T-1000 looked like the T-800, they would have ran towards him instead of away.

Answer (score -2):

Because the T-800 had different cybernetic skin, it was incompatible to the T-1000s sensors. Why would Skynet allow its later model mimic its previous model? It would make no sense. Especially after sending thousand of these things to fight on its front lines, it was trying to do away with using the same face that humans would probably recognize. So what did it do? It created the T-1000, which could imitate anything it touches (only organic human skin, not synthetic.)

Answer (score -3):

It couldn't mimic complex machines, like guns etc.

> It is capable of accurately mimicking voices as well, including the ability to extrapolate a relatively small voice sample to generate a wider array of words or inflections as required. However, its morphing abilities are limited by complexity, mass, and volume: it cannot transform into complex machines with mechanical moving parts or chemical fuels (like guns or bombs), and its volume prevents it from taking the form of a small object like a pack of cigarettes, although it is capable of impersonating larger people.

<sub>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-1000)</sub>

Comment: I don't think the T-1000 would have to simulate the complex parts of the T-800, because its only modeling the exposed exterior.  But I could be wrong, I'm not sure what the cannon answer is.

Comment: The question specifically said it was about mimiquing T800s **looks**, not its internal mechanisms. It looks like a human and T1000 can mimique a human (pretend it met real Arhnold).

Comment: Got it, I miss read that.

Comment: Oh, the larger people restriction is documentated) But what about the guy in the asylum then? He was a little larger person. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Regarding the heavier asylum guy, one possibility is reducing its density thereby increasing its volume. An example was, as you pointed out, the floor. (Ice, Water and Steam do it all the time)

Comment: Perhaps it would've had a hard time mimicking a T-800 with parts sticking out of a broken off arm.